# How can I pass an expression to a prefix argument?

Tags: prefix-argument

Sometimes it would be useful to be able to pass an expression to a prefix argument, for example

```
c-u 3*4 c-n
```

If I try the command above though it will print three asterisks followed by the '4' character then cursor-down.

Is there something I can do so the prefix argument can be the value of an expression?

Comment: I don't think that is possible without rebind C-u ; according to the documentation : Begin a numeric argument for the following command.
Digits or minus sign following C-u make up the numeric argument.
C-u following the digits or minus sign ends the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no convenient interface for that.

For some simple operations, you can make use of two facts:

- Using `C-u` with no number gives you powers of 4. `C-u C-n` moves 4 lines down, `C-u c-u C-n` moves 16 lines down, etc. (There are rare exceptions with commands that treat the no-number case differently.)
- The prefix argument is usually a repeat count, so you can do additions by repeating the command.

If you want a complex calculation, you can use `M-:` (`eval-expression`) to call the command. First, if you need to, look up the command name by pressing `C-h c` (or `f1 c`) and the keyboard shortcut you meant to invoke. To copy-paste the command name, switch to the `*Messages*` buffer, or alternatively use `C-h k` rather than `C-h c` and switch to the `*Help*` buffer. Then invoke `eval-expression` with `M-:` and specify `M-: (the-command-name (the-argument-expression))`. This assumes that the prefix argument is the sole argument to the function, which is often but not always the case: check the function's documentation.

Another approach, which works regardless of how the command consumes its prefix argument, is to set `prefix-arg` explicitly. invoke `eval-expression` with `M-:` and specify `M-: (setq prefix-arg (the-argument-expression))`, then immediately invoke the command. Under the hood, commands read the prefix argument from `current-prefix-arg`. Between each interactive command, Emacs sets `current-prefix-arg` to the value of `prefix-arg` and resets `prefix-arg` to `nil`.

Comment: This is an excellent solution. Yes, I can make a command such as `(goto-line (* 3 4))`, or elaborate on that idea as much as I like, eg `(goto-line (+(* row 4)5))` to offset the start of the blocked text in the file, for example. Thank you.